# Inserting data into a database from vb6?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, vb6

i am working on a program that takes some data from a listview object and should among other things insert the data into specific fields in a database. i am using vb6 and a ms access 2003 database. im not entirely sure how to connect to the database in vb6 although i do have this code at the moment

```
Option Explicit
Public dbCaseGoods As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim Barcode() As String
Dim linenumber As Integer
Dim strinsert As String



Private Sub btnDone_Click()
linenumber = 1
strinsert = "INSERT INTO Work_Order (PO_Number,CNC_Code,Line_No) VALUES ('" & "PO NUMBER" & "', '" & "CNC CODE" & "', '" & "LINE NUMBER" & "')""
'strinsert = "INSERT INTO Work_Order (PO_Number,CNC_Code,Line_No) VALUES ('" & ListView1.ListItems(linenumber).Text & "' , '" &     ListView1.ListItems(linenumber).SubItems(1) & "','" &     ListView1.ListItems(linenumber).SubItems(2) & "')""
Set rs = dbCaseGoods.execute(strinsert, dbfailonerror)

txtbarcode.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub Command1_Click()
Form2.Show
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
Set dbCaseGoods = OpenDatabase("I:\Casegoods\database\Contract_Casegoods.mdb")

ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="P.O#", Width:=ListView1.Width / 3
ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="Cnc Code", Width:=ListView1.Width / 3
ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="Line #", Width:=ListView1.Width / 8
End Sub



Private Sub txtbarcode_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
Dim li As ListItem


Barcode = Split(txtbarcode.Text, "-")
On Error Resume Next
   If KeyAscii = vbKeyReturn Then
   Set li = ListView1.ListItems.Add(, , Barcode(0))
   li.SubItems(1) = Barcode(1)
   li.SubItems(2) = Barcode(2)
   txtbarcode.Text = ""
   Command2.Caption = ListView1.ListItems(1).Text
   Command3.Caption = ListView1.ListItems(1).SubItems(1)
   Command4.Caption = ListView1.ListItems(1).SubItems(2)
End If

End Sub
```

what i am getting right now when i try to hit the button to insert the one line of data into the database is an error stating `Expected function or variable` and `.Execute` is highlighted in `Set rs = dbCaseGoods.execute(strinsert, dbfailonerror)`

Comment: Just `dbCaseGoods.execute strinsert, dbfailonerror`. No `Set rs = ` and no parentheses.

Comment: thank you for clearing that up! its working fine for now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An INSERT query does not return records so

```
Set rs = dbCaseGoods.execute(strinsert, dbfailonerror)
```

won't work. Just use

```
dbCaseGoods.Execute strinsert, dbFailOnError
```

You should also look into using [parameter queries](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/142938) instead of "gluing together" SQL statements.

Comment: Okay now it is giving me a compile error, `Expected Function or Variable`

Comment: @NickHallick Please edit your question to show your updated code and indicate what is highlighted when the compile error occurs.